# same data provider for chart and data grid

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I want to display the same data in a chart and a data grid. I want to use the same data provider for both of them to reduce the amount of SQL queries.

**How do I transform the database structure into the chart structure and into the table structure using ActionScript?***

Database structure in JSON format:

```
[
    {key:, year:, value:},
    {key:, year:, value:}
]
```

Data provider structure required by a chart:

```
[
    {series1:, series2:, year:},
    {series1:, series2:, year:}
]
```

Data provider structure required by data grid:

```
[
    {key:, year2000:, year2001:, ...},
    {key:, year2000:, year2001:, ...}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple  Util Class that parse the data and return  it a specidic componenet

for example

dataGrid.dataProvider = DataUtil.parseForDG(SQLData);
chatData = DataUtil.parseForChat(SQLData);

etc.....